# How do I set up an `A record`?

Tags: apache, dns, amazon-aws

I have Apache installed on an EC2 instance (with an Elastic IP). I successfully used [NameCheap](http://www.namecheap.com/)'s DNS tool to configure routing of www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com traffic.

If I have a web application living at www.mydomain.com/MyApp, what steps do I take to route MyApp.mydomain.com traffic to www.mydomain.com/MyApp? I don't want it to be a redirect.

Comment: DNS is so far out of my comfort area that I don't even know if I should be asking about `A`, `CNAME`, or `DNAME` records.

Comment: Out of interest why not 301 redirect?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @bybe. A 301 redirect in your .htaccess file would do the trick.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapp\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/myapp/$1 [R=301]
```